# How can I encapsulate multiple commands of get width between two nodes into one command?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a newbie of LaTeX and TikZ. I have below TikZ commands

```
\newdimen{\tempx}
\newdimen{\tempy}
\pgfextractx\tempx{\pgfpointanchor{node1}{west}};
\pgfextractx\tempy{\pgfpointanchor{node2}{east}};
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\tempwidth}{\tempy-\tempx-\pgflinewidth};
```

I want to reuse the snippet a lot, with a encapsulated command like

```
\extractwidth{node1.west,node2.east,\tempwidth}
```

Is that possible to encapsulate above commands with a `\newcommand` or similar method?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps s.th. like this, using `\NewDocumentCommand` with argument-preprocessor `\SplitArgument` of module ltcmd.dtx of recent LaTeX 2ε-kernels/of package xparse with not that recent LaTeX 2ε-kernels.

```latex
%\usepackage{xparse}
\newdimen{\tempx}
\newdimen{\tempy}
\NewDocumentCommand\extractwidth{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{%
  % Split #1 at commas, you get something like 
  % \extractwidthdotsplit{node1.west}{node2.east}{\tempwidth}%
  \extractwidthdotsplit#1%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand\extractwidthdotsplit{>{\SplitArgument{1}{.}}m>{\SplitArgument{1}{.}}mm}{%
  % Split the first two arguments at dot, you get something like
  % \extractwidthsplittedt{node1}{west}{node2}{east}{\tempwidth}%
  \extractwidthsplitted#1#2{#3}%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand\extractwidthsplitted{mmmmm}{%
  \pgfextractx\tempx{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{#2}};%
  \pgfextractx\tempy{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{#4}};%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{#5}{\tempy-\tempx-\pgflinewidth};%
}%
%...
\extractwidth{node1.west,node2.east,\tempwidth}%
```

Comment: worked for me, thanks